# Alignment of two DIVS and page resizing

Tags: html, css

I need to align two divs on the page so that when it is resized, the main div goes up and the other div down (a good example of this is the Twitter layout.)

```css
#corpoForm {
  min-width: 30%;
  padding: 2%;
  padding-top: 7.5%;
  float: right;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14pt;
  background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(255, 109, 13);
}

#vermelha {
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#tudo {
  display: table;
  background-color: darkmagenta;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
  <div id="corpoForm"></div>
  <div id="vermelha"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use display: flex; on the parent element and switch the direction (row or column) with a media query in css.